# Class Not Found Calling a Laravel Script from Supervisord

Tags: php, laravel, centos7, supervisord, laravel-queue

I'm using Laravel workers to execute some background tasks.
When I invoke the worker using 'php artisan queue:work', it works without any problem

But when I add the same command to supervisord in CentOS, using the following congifuration:

> [program:laravel-worker]
>
> process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d command=php
>
> /var/www/html/laravel/artisan queue:work
>
> autostart=true
>
> autorestart=true
>
> user=root
>
> numprocs=8
>
> redirect_stderr=true
>
> stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/worker.log

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in
> /var/www/html/laravel/app/External/library/RegistrationServi‌​ce.php
> on line 169
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class
> 'SoapClient' not found

The jobs are not executed complaining that SoapClient is not found (although it is installed). The SoapClient class is inherited by a plain PHP class that I load externally.

Note that I can use this class via the controller or the jobs when executed from command line without any problem, only in supervisord it's giving me the error message. To make things more weird, it happens only with one job that utilizes this external class, it doesn't happen with jobs that utilize Laravel's classes (controllers, events, etc...) only.

Comment: It might be worth sharing the errors where you stated "complaining that SoapClient is not found" or the code that invokes it

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in /var/www/html/laravel/app/External/library/RegistrationService.php on line 169

                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'SoapClient' not found

Comment: better to edit your question with it

Answer (score 0):

For `SoapClient` in Laravel 5.2:

1. add `'SoapClient' => SoapClient::class,` in `Config/app.php`
2. add `use SoapClient;` in your controller.
3. use `soapClinet` in your function: `new SoapClient('...')`;

Comment: none of the above made a difference
the exact same code already works on an Ubuntu server, and it works on the target CentOS server when php artisan queue:work is invoked manually from terminal. the problem has to do with supervisord on CentOS

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by specifying the exact path of the php binary
I still don't understand why it didn't pick the default one

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got this problem today.

And solve this by

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl upload
sudo service supervisord restart
```

with lucky I got rid off this Class Not Found Exception